# Regex to match multiple whole words

Tags: regex, wxwidgets

How do I write a regex, **that works in wxRegEx**, to match something this pseudo regex: `*good|better|best*` ?

I know about regex matching at the character level, i.e. `*.[ch]pp`, but how does it go as far as whole words go?

Thanks.

Comment: http://rubular.com/r/UahBdaQNhi ?

Comment: @marcog this is a great resource, thanks! Why does '\b(good|better|best)\b' work there but not in wxRegEx?

Comment: Another nice resource: http://www.regexguru.com/2008/04/wxregex-class-in-wxwidgets/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is a good example of why you should always specify the *flavor* of regex you're using.  Most regex flavors provide a way to match word boundaries, and most of those use `\b` for that.  According to [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wxwidgets.html), wxRegEx lets you choose one of three flavors: BRE, ERE, or ARE.  Of those, only ARE supports word boundaries, and it uses `\y`, not `\b`.  Assuming you specify `wxRE_ADVANCED` when you compile it, this regex will match any string that contains one of the words `good`, `better`, or `best`:

```
\y(good|better|best)\y
```

Judging by the examples you used, I think you may be confusing regexes with globs.  For example, `*.[ch]` is the glob you'd use to match file names ending with `.c` or `.h`; the regex for that would be `\.[ch]$`.  There's a good regex tutorial at the site I linked to earlier, but the difference I'm most concerned with is that a regex doesn't have to describe the whole string like a glob does.  That's why I didn't have to start the regex with `.*`, but I *did* have to add `$` to the end, to keep it from matching strings like `foo.cs` or `bar.html`.

Comment: This is a remarkable answer. Thank you! I don't have enough points to give you points but at least I can comment and say that (1) You highlighted the fundamental difference between a glob and a regex. (2) You noted the requirement for wxRE_ADVANCED (it seems that it's not enabled on my system because \y doesn't work either). (3) You provided an excellent link for an overview of wxRegEx. Thanks!

Comment: Ah! I just realized that by "specify wxRE_ADVANCED when you compile it" you meant "call wxRegEx::Compile()". Going to try it now...

Comment: Cool.  I didn't have access to wxWidgets to test this, so thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

`good|better|best`

I don't know what you mean by "elegant". As far as I'm concerned, that's pretty elegant.

Comment: Well, the pseudo regex that I gave is... **pseudo**. It doesn't really work. I need one that **works**. I tried **.\*\b(one|two|three)\b.\*** but that doesn't work either.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? What language are you using? What's your input and what do you get?

Comment: I am using wxRegEx. By doesn't work I mean it issues the error "Error: Invalid regular expression '\*one|two|three\*': quantifier operand invalid". It doesn't even get to the text to match stage (interactive regex test program).

Comment: That's because `*` is a quantifier. If you put it after a character (or group), it'll match that character zero or more times. If you just put it at the front like that, it's an error because you haven't put it after a character. If you tell us (by editing the original question) what your input is, what the regular expression you've tried is, what you're expecting to get out, and what you actually get (errors or otherwise), then we can help you a lot more efficiently.

Comment: Well, you said in your first reply "that's pretty elegant", implying that it works? I am just answering your question. Any idea why '\b(good|better|best)\b' works in http://rubular.com but not in wxRegEx? (wxRegEx doesn't issue an error but doesn't match either)